# CSS floating input and submit button in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, input

So I am obviously not super advanced in CSS but usually I can figure these out on my own, not this time though.

I am trying to have my search button float:left of my input field, all this is happening in an absolute position in my header.

Although I'm sure I may use some improper shortcuts to align my stuff the way I want, I did manage to have it display on explorer but it doesn't work on chrome (and apparently firefox too)

The html relevant to my problem:

```
    <div id="search-bar">
                    <div id="search-input">
                        <form action="#" method="get">
                            <p class="search"> 
                                <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
                            </p>
                            <p class="submit"> 
                                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
                            </p>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and the css:

```
#search-input p{
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
outline:0;
}

#search-bar{
position:absolute;
bottom: -10px;
right:0;
height: 55px;
width: 500px;
background: #e6e5e5;
border-radius: 10px;
}
#search-input{
position:absolute;
bottom: 10px;
right: 20px;
}

#search-input #search{
float:left
}

#search-input .submit input{
float:left
}

input{     
    border: solid 1px #E5E5E5;  
    outline: 0;  
    font: normal 13px/100% Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif; 
    width: 370px;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #FFFFFF;  
}  

input:hover, input:focus {   
    border-color: #C9C9C9;   
} 

.submit input {  
    width: auto;  
border: solid 1px #617798;
    background: #617798;  

font-size: 14px;  
    color: #FFFFFF;  
}

.submit input:hover {  
    background: #7187a8
}
```

Or if the problem is deeper down, here is the link to my practice folder: http://www.gfortin.com/css_practice/page.html

I would love to know how to fix it and to have any of my bad practices hinted out to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are after the CSS below. Once you make parent container #search-bar positioned, by setting the position to absolute as you have done, you need to position children relative to it hence position relative below.

```
search-input {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -9px;
    right: -17px;
}
```

Comment: Sweet, Thanks that did resolve the alignment in chrome and firefox! Since you here, would you happen to know why there is a 2px game between the button and input field and the button also seems to be 1px higher?

Comment: @gfortin13 2px between is a margin around the button. 1px is the border which is the same color as background on the text box, read up on the boxing model used by the browsers. Developer tools in Chrome is your friend <F12> will bring them up, if you are on windows.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think it's proper form to house input fields in paragraph fields, I would put those in divs, but it appears to be functioning so that would be your choice.

So, this isn't so much a CSS problem as it is an HTML problem. If you look at how your HTML is structured you actually have .search class before your .submit class in the DOM-- This means that when it comes to placing those elements the .search class will be placed first.

If you were to switch the placement in your HTML you should have an easy fix on your hands. I think it was just a case of you looking in the CSS instead of the HTML for a solution.

```
   <form action="#" method="get">
        <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </div>
        <div class="search">
            <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not exactly my problem, I don't want the search button on the left of the input bar (although it's nice and I might keep that way) the problem which you can see if you click my link is that the search bar and the input field aren't on the same line when they should (they are aligned on IE)

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh, so on your site you haven't specified a form width, so the relatively positioned elements inside it (.search and .submit) will stack because the form width would be inherit by default.

So if you select the form with css and add about a `width: 460px` that should allow the inputs to both be inline. I think IE interprets this situation differently then Chrome and Firefox which is why is might have worked on there.